# How i can Change the default table name in the admin interface in django

Tags: django, django-admin

[image]

I  need to change the newss   to another name
how i can do this ؟

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You must specify custom [verbose_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/options/#verbose-name) and [verbose_name_plural](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/options/#verbose-name-plural) in your Meta class for News model.

Comment: What if I want to change the word News in the blue banner, right on top of the highlighted Newss?

Answer (score 14):

Like this:

```
class News(models.Model):
    ......

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "News"
```

Then it will display "News" instead of "Newss"